# How do I display even and odd numbers based on user input? - java

Tags: java, while-loop

Please help... I need to write a program that displays even and odd numbers based on user input, but it loops forever during my last print statement.

Here is what I have so far, what's wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Integer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = 0;
  int odd = 0;
  int even = 0;

  System.out.println("How many numbers will be entered?");
  n = input.nextInt();

  while (n < 0 || n > 100) {
    System.out.println("ERROR! Valid range 0-100. RE-Enter:");
    n = input.nextInt();
  }

  while(n >= 0) {
    System.out.println("Now enter " + n + " integers: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();

  while(num > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
      } 
      else {
        odd++;
      }
        System.out.println("You entered " + odd + " odd numbers and " + even + " even numbers.");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, the indentation is wrong, for a start. Correcting this will help you find your problem. Otherwise, add print statements or use a debugger. Meaningful variable names might help to see the problem, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with too many while loops. You don't decrement `n` anywhere but you also loop on `num` while it's greater than 0. So it will loop forever if they stick something other than 0 in there.

```
System.out.println("Now enter " + n + " integers: ");
while(n >= 0) {
    int num = input.nextInt();
    if(num > 0) {
       if (num % 2 == 0)
         even++;
       else  
         odd++;
   }
   n--;
  }

  System.out.println("You entered " + odd + " odd numbers and " + even + " even numbers.");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = 0;
int odd = 0;
int even = 0;

System.out.println("How many numbers will be entered?");
n = input.nextInt();

while (n < 0 || n > 100) {
    System.out.println("ERROR! Valid range 0-100. RE-Enter:");
    n = input.nextInt();
}

while (n > 0) {
    System.out.println("Now enter integer " + n + ": ");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    } else {
        odd++;
    }
    n--;
}
System.out.println("You entered " + odd + " odd numbers and " + even + " even numbers.");
```

**Explanation**:
You handle `n` inputs from user and just check if the input is odd or even with an if-statement. You were over-complicating it.

Comment: so you would recommend to remove that statement? Or just add n--; somewhere?

Comment: Add `n--;` at the end of the `while (n >= 0)` loop.

Comment: Also in the end of the `while (num > 0)` loop, you should add a `num--;`, that should get you closer to the correct solution, whatever that is.

Comment: I just need to create a program that will allow a user to input how many integers he wants to enter, then enter that specific number of integers, and then it will tell you how many entered was odd and how many was even. It still loops no matter what.

Answer (score -1):

The infinite/forever loops is happening because of `input.nextInt()` and this is due to the behavior of `next()` method of Scanner class.

`next(), nextInt()` and its other variations do not move the cursor to the next line (end of current line - instead reads the first complete token with default delimiter as whitespace). `nextLine()` method on the other hand reads the whole input and moves the cursor to the next line.

Your code can be fixed by adding `input.nextLine()` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line before taking the next input. See below modified code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;

        System.out.println("How many numbers will be entered?");
        n = input.nextInt();

        while (n < 0 || n > 100) {
            System.out.println("ERROR! Valid range 0-100. RE-Enter:");
            n = input.nextInt();
        }


        for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Now enter integer " + (i+1) + " of " + n + " integers: ");

            int num = input.nextInt(); 
            while(num < 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR! Valid range 0-100. RE-Enter:");
                num = input.nextInt();
            }

            //this line is needed to move the input cursor to next line (due to use of nextInt() above)
            input.nextLine();

            if(i%2==0) {
                even++; 
            } else {
                odd++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("You entered " + odd + " odd numbers and " + even + " even numbers.");
    }
```

Comment: Actually the `while (n < 0 || n > 100)` is needed to keep bugging the user for correct input until it is received.

Comment: @ehehhh thanks for pointing out, i totally missed that ... anyway, updated the answer. The issue of forever looping was because of nextInt() method in the while loop. What do you think?